# How to prove that the intersection of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

How to prove that the intersection of  $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ space and $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ space is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ space?

Comment: The answer to that one proves a much more general statement, so I thought it might be instructive to see a concrete argument for the question at hand.

Answer (score 8):

If $f \in L^2(\mathbb R)$, then define $f_n(x)$ by $f_n(x) = f(x)$ if $|x| < n$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ if $|x| \geq n$.

Then $f_n(x) \in L^1(\mathbb R) \cap L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (f(x) - f_n(x)) = 0$ pointwise. So by the dominated convergence theorem
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb R}|f-f_n|^2 = 0 \tag1$$
The dominating function here is just $|f|^2$, since $|f-f_n| \leq |f|$.

Equation $(1)$ is equivalent to saying $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||f-f_n||_{L^2}^2 = 0$, so we have that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||f-f_n||_{L^2} = 0$ too.

So we conclude that $L^1(\mathbb R) \cap L^2(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: I know this is old but I cant see how $f$ is in the intersection. It is clear that it is in L^2 but I'm unable to see why it is in L^1.

Comment: $f$ is not in the intersection. It's an arbitrary member of $L^2$ and I'm showing that $f_n \in L^1 \cap L^2$ converge to $f$ in the $L^2$ norm as $n$ goes to infinity. That is what density means here.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I meant $f_n$. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's because by Holder's inequality or the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, $||f_n||_{L^1} = \int_{|x| < n}|f(x)| * 1 \leq (\int_{|x| < n} |f(x)|^2)^{1 \over 2} (\int_{|x| < n} 1^2)^{1 \over 2}$ is finite since $f \in L^2(R^n)$.